# FFMPEG hangs the whole nodejs process

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, response, pipe

What I am trying to do is to make a thumbnail of a video using ffmpeg. The video data is received in a HTTP request and then piped to ffmpeg. The problem is that once the ffmpeg child process exits I simply can't send the response back.

Here is the code:

```
var http = require('http'),
sys = require('sys'),
child = require('child_process')
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    im = child.spawn('ffmpeg',['-i','-','-vcodec','mjpeg','-ss','00:00:03','-vframes','1','-s','100x80','./thumb/thumbnail.jpg']);
    im.on('exit', function (code, signal) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end('{"success":true}\n');
     });
    req.connection.pipe(im.stdin);
}).listen(5678, "127.0.0.1");
```

The problem is that calling:

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
res.end('{"success":true}\n');
```

does nothing, the client never receives the response.

Comment: I'm not familiar with node.js but I cannot imagine that you need to create write raw json as a string to send json back to the user...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After two days of debugging and googling It seems like I have found the problem.
There are two related open bugs in node.js responsible:

- https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/777
- https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/782

I will try to describe what I think the problem is with the 'pipe' method:

The request stream fails to invoke end on ffmpeg.stdin (probably bug #777), this causes a broken pipe error, but node.js doesn't handle the error because of bug #782, meanwhile the request stream remains paused - this blocks any response from being sent.

The hack/workaround is to resume the request stream once ffmpeg exits.

Here is the fixed code sample:

```
var http = require('http'),
sys = require('sys'),
child = require('child_process')
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
im = child.spawn('ffmpeg',['-i','-','-vcodec','mjpeg','-ss','00:00:03','-vframes','1','-s','100x80','./thumb/thumbnail.jpg']);
    im.on('exit', function (code, signal) {
        req.resume();
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end('{"success":true}\n');
     });
  req.connection.pipe(im.stdin);
}).listen(5678, "127.0.0.1");
```

**Please keep in mind that this is a hack/workaround and may lead to problems with future node.js releases once they do something about those bugs**

Answer (score 2):

I would try something like this.

```
var http = require('http'):
var sys = require('sys'):
var child = require('child_process'):

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    im = child.spawn('ffmpeg',['-i','-','-vcodec','mjpeg','-ss','00:00:03','-vframes','1','-s','100x80','./thumb/thumbnail.jpg']);
    im.on('exit', function (code, signal) {
        res.end('{"success":true}\n');
    });
    req.connection.pipe(im.stdin);
}).listen(5678, "127.0.0.1");
```

You are trying to pipe out data to the socket before sending the header.

Comment: I have tried doing that already and it didn't work. As i said in the question the thumbnail is created and the child process 'exit' event gets called as it is supposed to, but the problem is that the response is never sent. It seems that ffmpeg somehow interferes with the server response.