# How to limit (or queue) calls to external processes in Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, queue

**Scenario**

I have a Node.JS service (written using [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com)) that accepts image uploads via DnD ([example](http://imgscalr.com)). After an image is uploaded, I do a few things to it:

1. Pull EXIF data from it
2. Resize it

These calls are being handled via the [node-imagemagick](https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick) module at the moment and my code looks something like this:

```js
app.post('/upload', function(req, res){
  ... <stuff here> ....

  im.readMetadata('./upload/image.jpg', function(err, meta) {
      // handle EXIF data.
  });

  im.resize(..., function(err, stdout, stderr) {
      // handle resize.
  });
});
```

**Question**

As some of you already spotted, the problem is that if I get enough simultaneous uploads, every single one of those uploads will spawn an 'identity' call then a resize operation (from Image Magick), effectively killing the server under high load.

Just testing with `ab -c 100 -n 100` locks my little 512 Linode dev server up such that I have to force a reboot. I understand that my test may just be too much load for the server, but I would like a more robust approach to processing these requests so I have a more graceful failure then total VM suicide.

In Java I [solved this issue](https://github.com/thebuzzmedia/imgscalr/blob/master/src/main/java/com/thebuzzmedia/imgscalr/AsyncScalr.java) by creating a fixed-thread ExecutorService that queues up the work and executes it on at most X number of threads.

In Node.JS, I am not even sure where to start to solve a problem like this. I don't quite have my brain wrapped around the non-threaded nature and how I can create a async JavaScript function that queues up the work while another... (thread?) processes the queue.

Any pointers on how to think about this or how to approach this would be appreciated.

**Addendum**

This is not the same as [this question about FFMpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483553/ffmpeg-hangs-the-whole-nodejs-process), although I imagine that person will have this exact same question as soon as his webapp is under load as it boils down to the same problem (firing off too many simultaneous native processes in parallel).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The threads module should be just what you need:

https://github.com/robtweed/threads

Comment: Rob, looking at it now and glancing through the docs, yes it looks *exactly* like what I was looking for. Effectively equivalent to an ExecutorService in Java, but for Node. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since Node does not allow threading, you can do work in another process. You can use a background job system, like [resque](https://github.com/technoweenie/coffee-resque), where you queue up jobs to be handled into a datastore of some type and then run a process (or several processes) that pulls jobs from the datastore and does the processing; or use something like [`node-worker`](https://github.com/cramforce/node-worker) and queue your jobs into the workers memory. Either way, your main application is freed up from doing all the processing and can focus on serving web requests.

[Update] Another interesting library to check out is [hook.io](https://github.com/hookio/hook.io), especially if you like the idea of node-workers but want to run multiple background processes. [/Update]

[Edit]

Here's a quick and dirty example of pushing work that takes a while to run to a worker process using `node-worker`; the worker queues jobs and processes them one by one:

**app.js**

```
var Worker = require('worker').Worker;
var processor = new Worker('image_processor.js');

for(var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
  console.log("adding a new job");
  processor.postMessage({job: i});
}

processor.onmessage = function(msg) {
  console.log("worker done with job " + msg.job);
  console.log("result is " + msg.data.result);
};
```

**image_processor.js**

```
var worker = require('worker').worker;
var queue = [];

worker.onmessage = function(msg) {
  var job = msg.job;
  queue.push(job);
}

var process_job = function() {
  if(queue.length == 0) {
    setTimeout(process_job, 100);
    return;
  }

  var job = queue.shift();
  var data = {};

  data.result = job * 10;

  setTimeout(function() {
    worker.postMessage({job: job, data: data});
    process_job();
  }, 1000);
};

process_job();
```

Comment: Brandon, really appreciate the followup with all the alternatives and code snippets. Your Worker example of queuing up the work for a single Worker to churn through them is exactly what I was looking for (multiple node instances per core, each one with a worker process grinding on its image work queue). Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Brandon, in your updated snippet, in app.js you use require "Worker" (capital 'W') and in processor require "worker" (lower cased 'w'), are these two different class types or just a mistype? Also I don't quite understand process_job's flow... you call it at the end of the processor and if queue is empty, wait 100ms to recheck (ok so far) but then at the end of processing the job, in the last setTimeout, you post the result back to app but then call it again... I am assuming to keep that loop alive always waiting for work? Could the same have been done with 1 encompassing setInterval?

Comment: No, it's not a mistype--it has something to do with the implementation, the lowercase worker is an instance of `WorkerNode` and uppercase Worker is the constructor function `Worker`. You can see him exporting both in [`lib/worker.js`](https://github.com/cramforce/node-worker/blob/master/lib/worker.js) and this is how his code works in the readme. This confused me at first too. :)

Comment: The `setTimeout` at the end is to simulate a process that takes some time to complete, and facilitates only processing one job at a time. Basically, the logic was: "At the end of a job, check immediately to see if there's more work. If there is, process the job, and at the end, check immediately to see if there's more work. Etc." If there is *not* more work to do, it'll set a timeout and check again shortly. There are probably multiple better ways to handle this, I think an event driven architecture with a "currently working" flag would work quite well.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who thought Brandon's quick-and-dirty might be *too* quick-and-dirty, here's a variation that is no longer and doesn't have the unnecessary busy-wait.  I'm not in a position to test it but it should work.

```
var enqueue = function() {
  var queue = [];
  var execImmediate = function(fImmediate) {
    enqueue = function(fDelayed) 
      queue.push(fDelayed);
    };
    fImmediate();

    var ic = setInterval(function() {
      var fQueued = queue.shift();
      if (fQueued) {
        fQueued();
      } else {
        clearInterval(ic);
        enqueue = execImmediate;
      }
    }, 1000);
  };
  return execImmediate;
}();
```

Comment: Malvolio, tank you for posting the alternative approach... I am having a hair of brain-stickiness walking myself through it. Could you clarify what it would look like from a caller, for example, from an ExpressJS POST method or something, ensuring that no matter how many queries are in-bound, they are queuing up serialily and getting executed in-order? I can't tell if braces are missing up in the execImmediate block, but I am confused about that and then the use of enqueue down in the clearInterval block even though it looks out of scope at that point. I just want to understand this better.

Comment: You're right: I was missing a set of braces (now fixed).  The idea is that you always call `enqueue()` with a function; `enqueue` ensures that the functions it is given are called as early as possible (and in order) but no more frequently than once a second.  There are actually two functions that get named "enqueue": execImmediate and an unnamed function that just queues up the function to be called later. You can think of the setting of `enqueue` as indicating the state of the system (i.e. whether incoming functions can be executed immediately or not).